# Tap screen for sound(array of sound files), xcode and swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, uitapgesturerecognizer

CURRENTLY - I am in the midst of building a flashcard app.  The app displays an array of flash cards which the user can swipe left and right through(code below)As you can see there are 11 different image arrays (each containing a specific group of words)and all of those arrays add up to one final array.  I have an audio file to couple each image.

PROBLEM - I want to make it so when the user taps the screen the audio file will play.  For example, if the lake image is displaying and the user taps the screen, that lake.mp4 audio file will play, if the user swipes left too the lamb image and taps the screen then the lamb.mp4 audio file will play etc...  I know i have to add a tap gesture recognizer but im not sure how to make each audio file couple the correct image.

the code below is what I am currently working with.

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController , UIGestureRecognizerDelegate  {

@IBAction func home(_ sender: Any) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "home", sender: self)
}

@IBOutlet weak var imgPhoto: UIImageView!

struct List {
    let words: [String]
    var active: Bool
}

let list1 = List(words:["lake", "lamb", "lamp", "lark", "leaf", "leash", "left", "leg", "lime", "lion", "lips", "list", "lock", "log", "look", "love", "lunch"], active: true)

let list2 = List(words: ["ladder", "ladybug", "laughing", "lawnmower", "lemon", "leopard", "leprechaun", "letters", "licking", "lifesaver", "lifting", "lightbulb", "lightning", "listen", "llama"], active: true)

let list3 = List(words: ["alligator", "balance", "ballerina", "balloon", "bowling", "cello", "colors", "curlyhair", "dollar", "dolphin", "elephant", "eyelashes", "gasoline", "goalie", "hula", "jellyfish", "olive", "pillow", "pilot", "polarbear", "rollerskate", "ruler", "silly", "telephone", "television", "tulip", "umbrella", "valentine", "violin", "xylophone", "yellow"], active: true)

let list4 = List(words: ["apple", "ball", "bell", "bubble", "castle", "fall", "fishbowl", "girl", "owl", "pail", "peel", "pool", "smile", "whale", "wheel"], active: true)

let list5 = List(words: ["planet", "plank", "plant", "plate", "play", "plum", "plumber", "plus"], active: true)

let list6 = List(words: ["black", "blanket", "blender", "blocks", "blond", "blood", "blow", "blue"], active: true)

let list7 = List(words: ["flag", "flipflop", "float", "floor", "flower", "fluffy", "flute", "fly"], active: true)

let list8 = List(words: ["glacier", "glad", "glasses", "glide", "glitter", "globe", "glove", "glue"], active: true)

let list9 = List(words: ["clam", "clamp", "clap", "claw", "clean", "climb", "clip", "cloud"], active: true)

let list10 = List(words:["sled", "sleep", "sleeves", "slice", "slide", "slime", "slip", "slow"], active: true)

let list11 = List(words: ["belt", "cold", "dolphin", "elf", "golf", "melt", "milk", "shelf"], active: true)

var imageIndex: Int = 0

var imageList: [String] {

    let wordLists = [list1, list2, list3, list4, list5, list6, list7, list8, list9, list10, list11]



    let active = wordLists.reduce([]) { (result:[String], list:List) in
        if list.active {
            return result + list.words

        } else {
            return result
        }
    }

    return active

}




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    imgPhoto.image = UIImage(named: imageList[imageIndex])

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    imgPhoto.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    let leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(Swiped(gesture:)))
    leftSwipe.cancelsTouchesInView = false

    let rightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(Swiped(gesture:)))
    rightSwipe.cancelsTouchesInView = false

    leftSwipe.direction = .left
    rightSwipe.direction = .right

    view.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe)
    view.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipe)

}

func Swiped(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {

    if let swipeGesture = gesture as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer {

        switch swipeGesture.direction {

        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.right :
            print("User swiped right")

            // decrease index first

            imageIndex -= 1

            // check if index is in range

            if imageIndex < 0 {

                imageIndex = imageList.count - 1

            }

            imgPhoto.image = UIImage(named: imageList[imageIndex])

        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.left:
            print("User swiped Left")

            // increase index first

            imageIndex += 1

            // check if index is in range

            if imageIndex > imageList.count - 1 {

                imageIndex = 0

            }

            imgPhoto.image = UIImage(named: imageList[imageIndex])

        default:
            break //stops the code/codes nothing.
        }
    }
}
}
```

---

```
   import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController , UIGestureRecognizerDelegate  {



var imageIndex: Int = 0
@IBAction func home(_ sender: Any) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "home", sender: self)
}

@IBOutlet weak var imgPhoto: UIImageView!


let itemList:[Card] = [
    Card(image: UIImage(named: "alligator")!, soundUrl: "Alligator.m4a"),
    Card(image: UIImage(named: "apple")!, soundUrl: "Apple.m4a"),
    Card(image: UIImage(named: "ball")!, soundUrl: "Ball.m4a")
]



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer:)))
    imgPhoto.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    imgPhoto.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)

    imgPhoto.image = (itemList[0] ).image

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    imgPhoto.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    let leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(Swiped(gesture:)))
    leftSwipe.cancelsTouchesInView = false

    let rightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(Swiped(gesture:)))
    rightSwipe.cancelsTouchesInView = false

    leftSwipe.direction = .left
    rightSwipe.direction = .right


    view.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe)
    view.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipe)

}

func imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{

    itemList[imageIndex].playSound()
    // Your action
}

func Swiped(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {

    if let swipeGesture = gesture as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer {

        switch swipeGesture.direction {

        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.right :
            print("User swiped right")

            // decrease index first

            imageIndex -= 1

            // check if index is in range

            if imageIndex < 0 {

                imageIndex = itemList.count - 1

            }

            imgPhoto.image = itemList[imageIndex].image

        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.left:
            print("User swiped Left")
            // increase index first

            imageIndex += 1

            // check if index is in range

            if imageIndex > itemList.count - 1 {

                imageIndex = 0

            }



            imgPhoto.image = itemList[imageIndex].image
        default:


            break //stops the code/codes nothing.
        }
    }
}
}
```

---

```
import Foundation; import UIKit; import AVFoundation


class Card: NSObject
{
var image: UIImage
var soundUrl: String
var player: AVAudioPlayer?

init(image: UIImage, soundUrl: String) {
    self.image = image
    self.soundUrl = soundUrl
}
    func playSound()
{
    guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: self.soundUrl, withExtension: "m4a") else { return }
    do
    {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

        player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
        guard let player = player else { return }
        player.play()
    print("hhh")
    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More Formatted Structure use modeling concept with MMVM architecture

```
import AVFoundation

        class Card: NSObject 
        {
          var image: UIImage
          var soundUrl: String
          var player: AVAudioPlayer?

          init(image: UIImage, soundUrl: String) {
            self.image = image
            self.soundUrl = soundUrl
          }


        func playSound() 
        {
            guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: self.soundUrl, withExtension: "mp3") else { return }
            do 
            {
                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

                player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
                guard let player = player else { return }

                player.play()
            } catch let error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
        }
```

**Usage**

```
 class SecondViewController: UIViewController , UIGestureRecognizerDelegate  {



    var imageIndex: Int = 0
    @IBAction func home(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "home", sender: self)
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var imgPhoto: UIImageView!


    let itemList:[Card] = [
        Card(image: UIImage(named: "lake")!, soundUrl: "lake.mp3"),
        Card(image: UIImage(named: "river")!, soundUrl: "river.mp3"),
        Card(image: UIImage(named: "ocean")!, soundUrl: "ocean.mp3")
        ]



    override func viewDidLoad() {

super.viewDidLoad()

let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer:)))
imgPhoto.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
imgPhoto.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)




        imgPhoto.image = (itemList[0] as! Card).image

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        imgPhoto.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        let leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(Swiped(gesture:)))
        leftSwipe.cancelsTouchesInView = false

        let rightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(Swiped(gesture:)))
        rightSwipe.cancelsTouchesInView = false

        leftSwipe.direction = .left
        rightSwipe.direction = .right

        view.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe)
        view.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipe)

    }


      func imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{

itemList[imageIndex].playSound()
    // Your action
}
    func Swiped(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {

        if let swipeGesture = gesture as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer {

            switch swipeGesture.direction {

            case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.right :
                print("User swiped right")

                // decrease index first

                imageIndex -= 1

                // check if index is in range

                if imageIndex < 0 {

                    imageIndex = imageList.count - 1

                }

                imgPhoto.image = itemList[imageIndex].image

            case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.left:
                print("User swiped Left")

                // increase index first

                imageIndex += 1

                // check if index is in range

                if imageIndex > imageList.count - 1 {

                    imageIndex = 0

                }

                imgPhoto.image = itemList[imageIndex].image
            default:


                break //stops the code/codes nothing.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Your last doubt solution**

```
let firstList:[Card] = [
        Card(image: UIImage(named: "lake")!, soundUrl: "lake"),
        Card(image: UIImage(named: "lamb")!, soundUrl: "lamb"),
        Card(image: UIImage(named: "lamp")!, soundUrl: "lamp")
           ]
struct List {
    let words: [Card] /*Create array of cards*/
    var active: Bool
}

let list1 = List(words:firstList, active: true)
let list2 = List(words:secondList, active: true)

 let wordLists = [list1, list2]

print((wordLists[0] as! List).words[0].soundurl)

**OUTPUT**
lake
```

Comment: I added the revisions in my code and got some errors.  since I am making each card an object it will not let me make a string out of them.  I am also getting an expected declaration error. I edited the question and posted the revised code and errors.

Comment: okay so I put card class in a seperate file.  Xcode is telling me there is no such module as AVPlayer.  Also at what point should I insert  words[index].playSound()? I keep on getting the error "expressions are not allowed on the top level" . Also I am getting an error for my superviewdidload saying that super cannot be used outside of class members.   Thank you

Comment: Thank you.  As you can see from my original code the words were grouped into 11 different lists and then each list had a string of words and had active = true at the end.  This is because i have a settings page to turn on and off each word list.  How can i have 11 different "itemList" and have each list active = true? because now it is no longer a string, before each list had a string of words.

Comment: okay so i am just running the demo with the 3 images. the app compiles without any errors.  when i run the app i can swipe through the images but there is no sound when I click

Comment: I have not added any tap gesture.  So far I have made the card class which contians the func play sound and I have added your modified code to my second view controller.

Comment: i mean to say is your soundPlay function called inside Card class log it if not called then you have to add tap gesture

Comment: okey your card class is fine just log on soundplay method and checked is called or not when you click

Comment: to log i should add print line somewhere?

Comment: I added it right before player.play()                                                             
    guard let player = player else { return }
            print("helo")
            player.play() .   It does not print any line

Comment: it means you have not added tap gesture add tap gesture to image view and put this code inside tap gesture method

Comment: I am a bit confused would you mind editing your answer and add the tap gesture recognizer? Thank you

Comment: Okay so I added that and still does not play sound.  I added print("") in the soundPlay function but the line does not print so maybe that could be part of the problem?

Comment: I have added my most recent secondviewcontroller and card classes to the question above for you to see.  Thank you

Comment: no the sound does not play.  I added the card and secondviewcontroller classes to my question above so you can see them.  Thank you

Comment: I added print("hhh") to  func imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
    {
        print("hhh")
        itemList[imageIndex].playSound(print("hhh"))
        // Your action
    } .  It does print the line.  So the tap gesture recognizer is working, the sound just is not playing

Comment: Hello, the sound works now!!!!! Thank you for your time!!! Can you just tell me how I can split the words into 11 different groups like my original code above and make each list active = true?

Comment: i started a chat

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using array of objects instead of using 2 different arrays.

For example. Create the following class:

```
class Card: NSObject {
  var image: UIImage
  var soundUrl: String

  init(image: UIImage, soundUrl: String) {
    self.image = image
    self.soundUrl = soundUrl
  }
}
```

Then you can create an array of your Card objects for example:

```
let cards = [
        Card(image: UIImage(named: "lake"), soundUrl: "lake.mp3"),
        Card(image: UIImage(named: "river"), soundUrl: "river.mp3"),
        Card(image: UIImage(named: "ocean"), soundUrl: "ocean.mp3")
    ]
```

Then when user swipes use the array `cards` to access the image or sound url. Each element of the array is a `Card` which has 2 properties: UIImage and String (url to your sound).

PS: The model is just an example, it could be UIImage + URL etc. Depends on your needs.

Comment: your answer is correct and also use MVC architecture, but still we can improve answer by using MVVm architecture

Comment: @JaydeepVyas agree but let's be honest. the person who asks the question sounds very junior. i don't think we should complicate the answer. let it be simple.

Comment: hello, please check my question about adding two arrays.  there is a bounty of 50 reputation points if you can answer it.